# Relative consistency of slightly modified GCH

Tags: logic, set-theory

Is it consistent with ZFC that $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$ for all regular $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa=\kappa^{+}$ for all singular $\kappa$?

Comment: I don't know the topic too well, but my guess would be that the model you get from applying [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem) in which $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$ for regular $\kappa$ would already satisfy $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for singular $\kappa$.

Comment: Wojowu is correct. Starting from a model of GCH and doing the appropriate Easton forcing will give you a model with your properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

Easton's theorem tells us that if $F(\kappa)$ satisfies $\operatorname{cf}(F(\kappa))>\kappa$, then it is consistent that for all regular cardinals $F(\kappa)=2^\kappa$, and for singular cardinals the least possible value is taken.

Starting with a model of $\sf GCH$ the function $F(\kappa)=\kappa^{++}$ satisfies the needed conditions, and it is not hard to check that for singular cardinals the least possible value is indeed $\kappa^+$.

So this theory is indeed equiconsistent with $\sf ZFC$. If, however, you want for *all* cardinals to satisfy $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$, you will have to assume the consistency of some large cardinals as this will imply the violation of $\sf SCH$ at every singular cardinal. But this is possible, if you assume the consistency of enough large cardinals. [This MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/79920/7206) and the linked questions there are relevant to this.

Comment: Cool. I always wanted to check this consistency as (although I know that there is no "right" axiom to add to ZFC) this would be my intuitive choice at gun-point. How satisfactory is this choice from modern set theorist's point of view? (I'm not a set theorist, just a secret admirer of set theory)

Comment: How satisfactory? I don't know. Depends on your personal mojo. Some people feel that $\sf CH$ is true and that $\sf GCH$ is supposed to be true; other feel that axioms like $\sf PFA$ should be true, instead, and they imply that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$. So it's hard to say how satisfactory this sort of behavior of the continuum function might be.